# how to get user id for flickr?

Tags: android, flickr

I am creating an app which is related to get the images from `flickr` but in this by passing user id we will get the images from a particular account with providing user id manually.

but i required the  user id when user `login` with username and password.

how can get user id by passing username and password?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your formulation is not really clear, but if what you are asking is how to get the user ID from the user name, since flickr uses [OAuth](http://www.flickr.com/services/api/auth.oauth.html); a quick look at the api documentation can give you the query you need to use:

[lookupuser](http://www.flickr.com/services/api/flickr.urls.lookupUser.html) seems useful or
[findbyusername](http://www.flickr.com/services/api/flickr.people.findByUsername.html)
the first one gives you the id corresponding to an user url, the second one the id corresponding to an username.

You just have to parse the response to get the id (unless flickr provides a wrapper that does the parsing for you but it does not seem to be the case:)

Comment: i have api_key and username from these parameters how can get user id and how can get response?

Comment: which url i have to call with providing username and api_key?

Comment: You should really have a look at the documentation of the API, that is where you will find this kind of answers...
In one minute I have found this url : 
http://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?method=flickr.people.findByUsername&api_key=57edf61d7683b38e266d5f726d44d697&username=killik&format=json&nojsoncallback=1&api_sig=b71ae7bbb8372f851f38a8533843441b